# The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 26.) - Three20 XML parser

Tags: iphone, three20, nsxmlparser, nsxmlparsererrordomain

I am constantly getting this error while parsing XML using NSXMLParser. The error I am getting is NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 26.

I have appropriate code to handle external entities but still the parser fails. Any comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text had HTML entities in addition to XML entities. Once removed things work fine now.